# RewriteRule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'am trying to update .htaccess  to redirect me from :
 **page.php/name** 
  to **page.php?id=name**.
 Can anyone help with example? I find a lot of example but not for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect (telling the browser that the request for **page.php/name** is at **page.php?id=name**, thus changing the URL in the location bar) you can do one of two things.

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page\.php/(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page\.php/(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

If you don't want a permanent redirect (301), then remove the `301` and `=301` parts from the above.

Comment: I try with this .htacces but it not work -.- what i forget?i am new in this .htacces thing. RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?blog\.php/(.*)$ /blog.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,R=301]